# How to center image?

Tags: css, html

I know that I'm missing something really small here but can't figure out how to get the large "SEO" image on the right side of this page centered back like it should be:  http://www.envisionlocal.com/index2.html

You can see where it is correctly centered on this page:  http://www.envisionlocal.com

But on the `index2.html` when you click on it I will be making a video load from YouTube.  Thanks!

Comment: How about investigating CSS properties in Chrome or Firebug? You seem to have extra HTML elements added that screw up the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from your `#content` CSS.

It currently has:

```
#content {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

which is forcing the image out of position, change this to `padding: 0`

(I investigated this with Web Inspector)

Comment: Also, transfer CSS of `.in-splash-right` to `.container` with few tweaks because it is our outer div now. Set divs inside it to `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. Again with few tweaks in style if something like padding etc messes it up

Answer (score 0):

If u r using APDIVS, u can check its CSS file and try positioning ur image according to the  left/right/top values of the div.